# Magento 2.3.3 Customer shipping address firstname trouble. "firstname" is required

Tags: magento, magento2

**Summary**

When I try to place an order after the customer registration/Login. Magento 2.3.3 shows "First Name is a required Field Error. Firstname field is not displayed. When I try create shipping address at profile page or at backend - firstname field is displayed but same validation error occured!

Data was migrated from 1.9.3.4 by Data migration tool

I read about same troubles in another versions magento but no solutions found

I try to play with eav_attribute and customer_eav_attribute. I put is_visible=1 and is_required=0 but It not helps

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Login
2. Checkout order
3. Fill shipping form
4. Error displayed: Please check the shipping address information. "firstname" is required. Enter and try again.

**Screenshots**

[image: Place order - firstname is hidden]

[image: Profile create shipping address]

[image: Backend = customer edit - shipping address add]

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue on my end after migration from Magenro 1.9 to magento 2.3.3, for me this way is working :
run on your mysql command line

> select attribute_id,attribute_code from eav_attribute where
> attribute_code="firstname";

it will showing like this

[image]

then run the following query , **don't forget to change attribute_id based on your end**:

```
INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES ('adminhtml_checkout', '5');
INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES ('adminhtml_customer_address', '5');
INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES ('adminhtml_customer_address', '20'); 
INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES ('customer_address_edit', '5'); 
INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES ('customer_address_edit', '20');
INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES ('customer_register_address', '20'); 
INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES ('customer_register_address', '5');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this issue after migrating from 1.9 to 2.4.3.

My solution was to back up the *customer_form_attribute* table and truncate it (remove all the data).

```
mysql> create table customer_form_attribute_bkup select * from customer_form_attribute;
mysql> truncate customer_form_attribute;
```

I then placed the following code which I had lifted/amended from *vendor/magento/module-customer/Setup/Patch/Data/DefaultCustomerGroupsAndAttributes.php* into a file in the root directory of my Magento 2 installation and ran it.

The customer_form_attribute table was rebuilt and everything worked after that.

```
<?php
 
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);


$objManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logger = $objManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);

$moduleDataSetup = $objManager->get('Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface');
$customerSetupFactory = $objManager->get('Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory');
$customerSetup = $customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $moduleDataSetup]);
$customerSetup->installCustomerForms();
```